# indexOf is red underlined

Tags: list, flutter, dart, arraylist

I tried to use `indexOf` in my code, but `indexOf` is red underlined and I don't know why...

This is my function:

```
  void test() {
     indexx = dateArrayTest.indexOf(formattedDate);
  }
```

And this are my imports:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fitnessapp2/main.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

This are the variables I use:

```
  int formattedDate = int.parse(DateFormat('yyyyMMddkkmm').format(date));
  var indexx;
  var dateArrayTest = {
    202201011940,
    202201011941,
    202201011942,
    202201011943,
    202201011944,
    202201011945,
    202201011946,
    202201011947,
  };
```

Do I need another import?

Comment: What type is `dateArrayTest`?

Comment: What error does your IDE report back to you? What type is `dateArrayTest` and `formattedDate`?

Comment: I have updated my question, now you can see my variables

Comment: Your `dateArrayTest` is not a `List` but a `Set` (you are using `{}` instead if `[]`). A `Set` does not have index positions of its elements and does therefore also not have the `indexOf` method.

Comment: Added an answer you can accept if it works. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your `dateArrayTest` is being declared as a `Set<int>` which does not have the `indexOf` method since elements of a `Set` cannot be requested by index.

If you need the `indexOf` method, you need to declare `dateArrayTest` as a `List<int>` by using `[]` instead of `{}`:

```
  var dateArrayTest = [
    202201011940,
    202201011941,
    202201011942,
    202201011943,
    202201011944,
    202201011945,
    202201011946,
    202201011947,
  ];
```